# Real-time data transfer via ODBC from MS Access to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I'm currently working on a Attendance & Payroll System. The developing appliction should be able to import the data from Finger Print Scanners.

The client already has 15 finger print machines installed at their premises and it exports to an MS Access database with the following fields

1. Employee ID
2. Date
3. Check-In
4. Check-Out

The system which we are going to develop will have a seperate MySQL Database.

How can i transfer the data in real-time from MS Access to MySQL?

Whenever a user punches their thumb it autmatically updates the MS Access database.

I want to do,

1. Data Migration for existing data - This is already accomplished
2. Transfer all real-time new data to MySQL

How can i accomplish the 2nd task?

I tried using an ODBC connector to mysql. it pulls the table from MySQL to MSAccess. I want to it other way around. ie. Pull the data from existing columns and insert it to mapped table in MySQL.

How can i do this?

Comment: "it pulls the table from MySQL to MSAccess" you mean like a linked table? You can write VBA code which will accomplish the task of reading from the Access table and writing to the mysql database. Or you could convert all the tables in Access to linked tables which actually point to the mysql database. Then anything added to Access will literally be written to MySQL automatically because that's where the table actually is.

Comment: Or another alternative - cut out the Access middleman and have the data exported from the scanners imported directly to MySQL.

Comment: @Adyson It doesn't support that. But however, we can dump an .sql file thus it won't save my purpose.  Supported formats are sql, mdb, csv. Currently it is set to mdb and it has huge amout of data. Data of past 10 years

Comment: if you export to CSV from the scanner you can import that to mysql very easily, the process is well documented by MySQL's documentation and others. Might be a bit more subtle if you're trying to append data rather than just dump a whole table, but still, reading individual rows from CSV and inserting them to MySQL is pretty trivial too, in almost any programming language you care to name.

Comment: @ADyson With CSV it will be a difficult task but Ideal solution would be using the VBA code as you said. Insert to MySQL employee table whenever there a transaction is inserted at MS Access. What do you think?

Comment: It's a reasonable solution, assuming the Access application is actually open when this occurs. If it's not, no VBA code will run. It's perfectly possible to write to an Access database file without opening Access - do you know how the scanner is doing it? I was thinking if you just wrote the data to CSV, a Scheduled Task could run every minute or two, read the csv file and pass on the latest data to mySQL.

Comment: Data macros are engine level code. No VBA or even access has to be loaded. However, I not tested if data macros can operate on linked tables. If they can't, then data macros will not help. If data macros can use linked tables (I not 100% sure if they can), then you can write table triggers in data macros. It all depends if Access is running (then VBA can be used). If the software is JUST using the Access database engine, then you can have procedure code run as a trigger (data macros).

Comment: i tried Data macros on the linked table as suggested by Erik in the Answer. Process was smooth but changes doesn't reflect on MySQL. Are there any possible bottle necks that i'll have to look into?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to transfer the new data.

What you do is use linked tables to MySQL so that all data resides on the MySQL server at all times.

Access is perfect able to use “linked” tables to Oracle, or SQL server or MySQL. When you use linked tables, then access functions as before, but ALL table data is live edited and is on the server – no transfer or sync is required.

Comment: Finger print machines already outs a pre-defined table and it has data. I also have a attendance table (MySQL) in my-end to dump the data from access to mysql. So is it possible to get it work on existing data? when i link a attendance table from Mysql, will access automatically transfer existing data? Or is there a solution like convert existing with table to linked table in MySQL and keep adding the new data?

Comment: Access does not transfer a linked table. You are using and editing the data "in place", which turns out to be on MySQL. Linked tables work the same as local tables - they are edited where they reside. No such data "transfer" occurs. No need to transfer data back and forth. So move your tables to MySQL, and link them from access. The only possible stumble block will be how the fingerprint software works with the access database - it might not work with linked tables - so this you have to test. If access program is your own creating, then for sure this can work.